# Deploy mutliple artifacts to the same folder using maven

Tags: maven

Currently we have one main pom file which builds the code for multiple modules using the module tag. When I use the "**mvn clean package deploy**" command (which references the main pom file and performs these actions fro all other modules), the packaged file(war/jar) for each module is placed in it's respective target directory. Since there are different modules and they have their own respective group-id,artifact-id etc. the packaged files are spread across different folders.

My applications consists of all of these modules and I need all the packaged files under one single folder. Till now we have used an ant script to copy the relevant files from all of these modules to a single folder.
Apart from copying the files/aggregating all the packaged files and then uploading it as part of **deploy:deploy-file** is there any way I can deploy all the files to the same folder?

Comment: I don't really understand your intention. When you build a multi-module project, the artifacts are built in their respective `target` directories (it is meant to be that way). After that they are deployed to some repository like Nexus or Artifactory. The directory structure in Nexus or Artifactory is completely determined by the groupId, artifactId, version etc.

Comment: Yes, that is expected. So I have an application which consists of all these modules. Currently an ant script is used to copy the relevant files to the release folder. Now that I am trying to deploy to artifactory, I was just wondering whether there is any way to deploy these modules to one common folder(which was done previous by copying files to a folder using ant) and also not change the existing configurations i.e the groupId,ArtifactoryId etc. of individual modules.

Comment: First the given command `mvn clean package deploy` already contains things which are not needed. If you like to deploy only `mvn clean deploy` is needed. `package` is included in the life cycle. To package several things of a build into zip/tar/ I recommend to use maven-assembly-plugin but why do you need to copy them via Ant? Please make a simplified example project which shows how it looks like and what you like to have? From my point of view it does not make sense cause the artifacts will be built and deployed into repo mngr... I hope you don't use `deploy-file` in your build? That WRONG!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

The directory structure in Artifactory is always of the form

```
org/something/artifact/1.2.3/artifact-1.2.3.jar
```

assuming groupId `org.something`, artifactId `artifact` and version `1.2.3`.

This structure cannot be changed.